# How do I grant 'all' permissions to a netbeans project? | netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I don't have a policy file or at least i can't find it, how do i grant `all` permissions to my java projects? I've seen solutions to edit a `my.policy` file and grant all permissions and add its path to `VM Options` but where can I find or how do I generate a policy file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global default policy has been set by the file `java\jre\lib\security\java.policy` in the JRE. And it is shared by all of the Java programs that run in the JVM on the node. Default permissions for the java.policy file can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=security-javapolicy-file-permissions).

For more information, please look at [Specifying Permissions with the Security Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/security/policy.html) and [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

Example of a custom policy file could be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/userperm/policy.html) and this policy file tells the Java security manager what to allow and disallow.